# How to find the Final Path from the Traversal Path while performing BFS/DFS algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve a problem which apples a Breadth-First Search Algorithm as well as Depth-First Search algorithm on a Tree and finds out the traversal and final paths that are found by both these algorithms.

What I am actually confused with is **how do I calculate these two different paths? And are they really different?**

For example, consider the following tree,

[image]

Let's say, that our starting node is **A** and Goal node is **H**

For both the algorithms, this is what I feel would be the Traversed and Final Paths

1. **For BFS**

**Traversal Path:** A B C D E F G H

**Final Path:** A C F H

If this is how it works, then how can I find that Final Path? Its very easy to find traversed path, but not exactly so easy to find the Final Path.

Similarly,

2. **For DFS**

**Traversal Path:** A B D E C F G

**Final Path:** A C F H

Again, how can I extract the Final Path from the Traversal Path for DFS.

This actually gets a bit more complicated. What if my Goal Node is reachable from two sides? How do I find the Final Path in such a scenario?

For example, Consider the following scenario,

[image]

Let's say for this case, our Starting Node is **A** and Goal Node is **H**, again.

Traversal path is very easy to compute with both BFS and DFS.

But for the Final Path, "H" is reachable from two sides, **it is reachable from F and it is also reachable from G**

For the DFS, you may write the final path as **A C F G** because from the F node, we would reach the H first (as G would still be unexplored, however you would still have to extract this Final Path from the Traversal path, which I do not know how to do)

**But for BFS, you can not do that. So, what would be my Final Path in this scenario? Should there be two Final Paths in such a scenario?**

Can anyone help me out in this please.

Comment: `Should there be two Final Paths in such a scenario?` -- this depends only on whether *you* want all paths or just one. However, your other questions are all answerable: the usual technique is to keep a map from each node to its 'parent node' in the traversal. You cannot do this reconstruction with *only* the traversal path, since that's like reconstructing a binary tree uniquely from just a preorder traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One [out of many possible] approach is to maintain a map of target to source node. Every time you advance, record which source node was made to make that advance. So, in BFS case it will look like:

```
parents = {
  'A': NULL,
  'B': 'A',
  'C': 'A',
  'D': 'B',
  'E': 'B',
  'F': 'C',
  'G': 'C' 
}
```

Then, from the final node, reconstruct the path by going backward:

```
node = target
path = []
while node:
   path.append(node)
   node = parents[node]
```

Same approach works for DFS and Dijkstra